# Use ASP Panel to order content items horizontally

Tags: html, css, asp.net, layout

Question is how to use ASP Net controls to put content in line order instead of wrapping them vertically.

This is how it should looks like (good):

[image: Good view]

This is what ASP looks like now (bad):

[image: Bad view]

How to avoid wrapping items to the next line in ASP Net without going back to old HTML and CSS?

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" BackColor="#FFCC99" Width="500px" Wrap="False">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" BackColor="#FF0066" Width="120px">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/msfp_smbus1_01.jpg" Width="64px" Height="64px" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" Width="160px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Title" CssClass="ProductTitle" Width="90px"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel6" runat="server" BackColor="Orange" HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Single"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel7" runat="server" BackColor="Blue">
            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Quantity"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel8" runat="server" BackColor="Red" ForeColor="White">
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Line"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panels get rendered as div, so you have to apply certain CSS to align them properly and as per your required layout. I've used `float:left` for all panels and gave them a proper width so they can align properly.

Try this

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" BackColor="#FFCC99" Width="700px" Wrap="False">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" BackColor="#FF0066" Width="120px" CssClass="left">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="CreatedImages/Component%205.jpg" Width="64px" Height="64px" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" Width="160px" CssClass="left">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Title" CssClass="ProductTitle" Width="90px"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel6" runat="server" BackColor="Orange" HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="left">
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Single"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel7" runat="server" BackColor="Blue" Width="160px" CssClass="left">
            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Quantity"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel8" runat="server" BackColor="Red" Width="160px" ForeColor="White" CssClass="left">
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Line"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
         .left
         {
             float:left;
         }
 </style>
```

Comment: One up for the linebreak solution for title/description which you posted as code to understand quick and simple how it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very single way to achieve it. Add the style `display:inline-block` to your panels. That will make them flow from left to right, as you want.You don't need to specify a width if you don't need.

If you need it, after all the panels you can add an empty `<div>` to "break the flow", so that the following elements appear "on the next line".

To apply the style, you can do two things:

1. define a CSS class, and specify it in the control `CssClass` property (on code behind or in the panel tag in the .aspx file)
2. add the style using `panelX.Style.Add("display","inline-block")` or `panelX.Style["display"] = "inline-block")` in the code behind

The class for 1 should look like this:

```
.inlineBlock {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

And, in your panel add `CssClass="inlineblock"`

See the [docs for display CSS attribute in w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that without CSS.

The Panel Element of ASP (http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_panel.asp) is just being rendered as a normal div in html. The panel itself got no attribute or method to call for making just as big as it needs to.

In this case you will need to use CSS with some style attributes like "display:inline" or "display:inline-block" just as you need it.

The only thing you could is setting the width absolutely in your code using the "Width" attribute.

Greetz